# Full screen on multiple monitors with Chrome Apps

Tags: css, video, fullscreen, css-animations, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to stretch a single full screen window across multiple (physical) screens with Google Chrome Apps?

I am producing two video signals (fill and alpha) and need to render these inside the same window to guarantee that they are synchronized. (Two windows tend to have two different draw cycles.)

Alternatively, is it possible to use two windows, but guarantee synchronized CSS animations between them?

Comment: I wonder if the solution for two equal sized screens will be the same as for two different sized screens.

Comment: "Fullscreen" usually means "one screen", unless your video drivers present one combined "screen". Multi-screen apps (I'm not talking about Chrome apps in particular) have, in essence, several full-screen windows.

Comment: How tight are your sync requirements?

Comment: The two screens will output 1080p50 so the sync has to be correct to 2ms.

Comment: Please include some code then to get an idea of your content.

Comment: No code yet for Chrome Apps. It is essentially the same div next to one another with classes being applied through Javascript. CSS animations hide, show and animate it, a SVG filter turns the second copy into a greyscale alpha channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement to play a single video stretched on multiple monitors with ultra-thin bezels and it works perfectly. Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
chrome.app.window.create("screen.html", {
  "state": "normal",
  "resizable": false,
  "innerBounds": {
    "left": -1920,
    "top": 0,
    "width": 5760,
    "height": 1080
  }
}, function (screenWindow) {
  screenWindow.contentWindow.addEventListener("load", function() {
    screenWindow.contentWindow.loadConfiguration(screen.ScreenId);
  });
});
```

Comment: I would guess `frame: "none"` is also needed. But that's an interesting hack if it works.